# Session limit of 10000 exceeded

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-api

Starting at around 2021-03-24 03:44:19.552 -07:00, we started getting the following error for any Session Request -- I have attempted to reduce the time period, but to no avail.  Please advise:

https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/sessions?startTime=2021-03-21T18:22:23.521Z&endTime=2021-03-21T19:22:23.521Z&quotaUser=id&prettyPrint=false:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Session limit of 10000 exceeded.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Session limit of 10000 exceeded.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalidArgument"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Comment: "I have attempted to reduce the time period" how much did you reduce the time period? The error is generated based on the number of points in the time window, so there should be some window length below which you don't get this error.

Comment: We are having the same issue @AndyTurner; we even reduce it to 1 millisec and we receive the error. Here an example: curl --request GET 'https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/sessions?startTime=2021-01-25T00:00:00.000Z&endTime=2021-01-25T00:00:00.001Z' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXX' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. In our case it happens only to a few users (40 out of 5.000 users approx)

Comment: We even filter by activityType and same thing happens...

Comment: @Jordi can you identify anything particular about the users who see this issue? Do they have lots of devices, specific devices, specific activities etc? Do you continue to get the issue if you shift the window by a few days (obviously you'd not get the data you want, I'm just trying to establish if the users have hotspots with high numbers of activities, or they have consistently high numbers).

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks a lot. With this specific user, we cannot retrieve session data for him at all (we can get datasources and aggregate). We didn't find a time window in which this does not happen. You made us thought that maybe this user has something in common with other users that happen the same. We will check other users' datasources and we will provide this information back to you soon.

Comment: This appears to have been resolved -- I've not noticed anything since 2021-04-02 16:46:01.356 -07:00.  Thanks!

Comment: @AndyTurner & Eric, yay! same here!!!

Comment: Thanks for confirming! There was a bug in the implementation of the limit; we've just bumped it up for now.